# Reading colors from a config file with ConfigParser to use with Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, configparser

In the config file I have the variable defined as

```
BackgroundColor = 0,0,0
```

Which should work for the `screen.fill` settings for Pygame or any color argument for that matter. Where I can just do `screen.fill(0,0,0)`

The problem I think is with this is that for integers read through a `configfile` I have to put `int()` to convert the string to an int. For something like colors int doesnt work and I have no idea what should be used.

```
TypeError: invalid color argument
```

That's the error from python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a string representing the color, e.g. `'0,0,0'`.  Use `split(',')` to split it into separate fields, then convert each one.

e.g.

```
color = '255, 255, 255'
red, green, blue = color.split(',')
red = int(red)
green = int(green)
blue = int(blue)
```

Or if you want to do it in one step and the comprehensions don't bother you:

```
color = '128, 128, 128'
red, green, blue = [int(c) for c in color.split(',')]
```

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what I thought, nice to get that second simpler code as well :)